# Lubuntu 15.04 running on VirtualBox doesn't switch to full screen

Tags: lubuntu, guest-additions

I have installed Lubuntu 15.04 on VirtualBox 4.3.18 on Windows 7 host. After installing VBox Guest addition 3.18 and the one with Ubuntu, I still don't get the Lubuntu in full screen. I have read other posts, even executed this shell on Guest OS.

[Forcing monitor resolution in VirtualBox VM on Linux Guest](https://superuser.com/questions/428159/forcing-monitor-resolution-in-virtualbox-vm-on-linux-guest#10726041)

How can I get Lubuntu to show in full screen?

Comment: You did reboot? Do you have the correct linux-headers package installed (on Linux)? Did you install dkms (also on Linux)?

Comment: I installed the dkms, and I reboot the linux several times, but about the correct linux-header package I am not sure. would you let me know how can I check it?

Comment: On another computer with windows 7 and VirtualBox 5.0.14 and Lubuntu 15.10 it worked fine.